# Error in repeating arrows with tkz-fct

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide, tikz-decorations, tkz-fct

Where do the extra arrows outside of the picture come from? Use `pdflatex --shell-escape` to typeset the sample code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\tikzset{
  arr/.style={
    postaction=decorate,
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 0.25 with {\arrow[thick,line width=0.5mm]{latex}},
      mark=at position 0.5  with {\arrow[thick,line width=0.5mm]{latex}},
      mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow[thick,line width=0.5mm]{latex}}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzFctPolar[domain=pi:2*pi,arr]{3} 
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is you actual question? At least if I put the code in overleaf and by changing `color=cyan` and `color=red`. The errors disappear.

Comment: The arrowhead out of plot (in cyan) this is the problem, is not a problem of the color.

Answer (score 1):

The optional argument of `\tkzFctPolar` is used twice, like `\tikzset{#1}\draw[#1]...;`, hence the finally accumulated marking positions are `0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75`. This breaks the `tikz` requirement that those positions must be *in increasing order*, see `pgfmanual` v3.1.8b, sec. 50.6,

> (doc for key `/pgf/decoration/mark=at position <pos> with <code>`)
>
> It is possible to give the `mark` option several times, which causes several markings to be applied. In
> this case, however, it is necessary that the positions on the path are in increasing order. That is,
> it is not allowed (and will result in chaos) to have a marking that lies earlier on the path to follow
> a marking that is later on the path.

A workaround: add `reset marks` in definition of style option `arr`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\tikzset{
  arr/.style={
    postaction=decorate,
    decoration={
      markings,
      reset marks, % <<< added here
      mark=at position 0.25 with {\arrow[thick,line width=0.5mm]{latex}},
      mark=at position 0.5  with {\arrow[thick,line width=0.5mm]{latex}},
      mark=at position 0.75 with {\arrow[thick,line width=0.5mm]{latex}}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzFctPolar[domain=pi:2*pi,arr]{3} 
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A `tikz` example showing the problem.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
  my decoration/.style={
    postaction={decorate},
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position .5 with {\fill[blue] circle (2pt);},
      mark=at position .75 with {\fill[blue] circle (2pt);},
      % this third mark breaks the increacing order requirements, hence will 
      % appear at a wrong position
      mark=at position .6 with {\fill[red] (-2pt,-2pt) rectangle (2pt,2pt);}
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\tikz
  \draw[my decoration] circle (1cm);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ¡Thanks a lot!, it works properly

Comment: @delta_with_hat Hi, I've added words about "why it breaks". Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, your MWE compiling with recent MikTeX throw error: `I cannot decorate an empty path` ...

Comment: @Zarko Run with `-shell-escape` (as mentioned in the question description). Internally `\tkzFctPolar` uses `\draw plot function {...};` hence will finally execute `gnuplot`.

Comment: thank you for explanation. T don't use `gnuplot` ... but this should be simple to draw with pure TikZ.